failed to link the ".a" library into the project
I faced challenges in linking the library file to my project.
I created a static library named "libadd.a" using e2 Studio IDE. Later, I initiated a Renesas microcontroller project in Visual Studio Code utilizing the Renesas Build Utilities extension. Unfortunately, I faced challenges in linking the library file to my project. Could someone kindly provide a solution or suggest changes to integrate the static library into my project?
For reference, I have attached the link to the project file:
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtpJeB_KPU0lhxafcoVB4Qf5vNfh?e=h3ZVcQ

Welcome to Stack Overflow! We collect a library of questions and answers which will be useful not only for the OP, but for other users. For that reason we expect code and error message to be directly in the question post, not as links. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] question post accordingly.
